# Binding Grid RowDefinition Height to ColumnDefinition Width

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, grid

I am trying to bind the the Heights of my `RowDefinition`'s to the Width of my `ReferenceColumn`.

```
<Grid x:Name="SelectionElements">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=Width.Value, ElementName=ReferenceColumn}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=Width.Value, ElementName=ReferenceColumn}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=Width.Value, ElementName=ReferenceColumn}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=Width.Value, ElementName=ReferenceColumn}" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ReferenceColumn" Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

But it is not working (no error or anything).

Answer (score 1):

Set the actual width:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ReferenceColumn}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ReferenceColumn}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ReferenceColumn}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ReferenceColumn}" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ReferenceColumn" Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ActualWidth instead of Width.